# I have a problem importing my data from google form, the variable "results" is not calling the format I need

Tags: r

```
URL <-"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRfIhVfhX6vQiA3niXIzmbq0JOcdtqjBxcv65cSA0AQ6tDDpQd3-R1OjR1eCRS3-OYgrAU4zJ-dHvZR/pub?output=csv"
txt = tryCatch(getURL(URL),error = function(e) {getURL(filename, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)})
tc = textConnection(txt)  # Opens a connection.
resultados <-  read.csv2(tc,header = T,stringsAsFactors = FALSE,encoding = "UTF-8")
datos <- resultados[, -1]
```

I need to import the excel table found in google form but it is calling a different format.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`download.file()` may be helpful from `utils`, like so:

```
URL <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRfIhVfhX6vQiA3niXIzmbq0JOcdtqjBxcv65cSA0AQ6tDDpQd3-R1OjR1eCRS3-OYgrAU4zJ-dHvZR/pub?output=csv"
download.file(URL, destfile="output.csv",method="libcurl")
```

Be sure to set the working directory wherever you want to download the file to `setwd()`.

You can then use `read.csv()` to read in the downloaded csv.